# Why can't I use the dependent variable in the selection equation as an independent variable in the outcome equation?

Tags: r

I use the example from the sampleSelection package, where I switch the dependent variable for the outcome equation to family income, because I want the labor force participation of the woman, lfp, to be a logical determinant.

```
library("sampleSelection")
data( Mroz87 )
Mroz87$kids <- ( Mroz87$kids5 + Mroz87$kids618 > 0 )
selection2 <- selection(selection = lfp ~ age + I(age^2) + faminc + kids + educ, 
                    outcome = faminc ~ lfp + wage + age + exper, 
                    data = Mroz87, method = "2step")
```

My problem is that adding lfp as an independent variable in the outcome equation prevents a solution. I get:

```
Error in solve.default(crossprod(xMat)) : 
Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[6,6] = 0
```

Removing lfp from the outcome allows a solution, but not the one I seek. I think I've read that the problem is in the matrix mathematics running underneath (singularity prevents inversion, maybe?). Is there a way to get the solution I want, a work around maybe?

Comment: Your site link is broken.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You said " I’ve seen on this site" but don't give the link for the site.

Comment: @user227710 Thanks. I re-worded. I am new at this, and have a lot to learn.

Comment: I added a package reference. If it's wrong, please add the correct package you're using (for the data).

Comment: @ Roman and others. I reworded the question, including a package reference. Thank you for any help or guidance.

Comment: @Tony: The problem is your solution:  you are not supposed to add `lfp` as an independent variable in the outcome equation. You would be better off asking this question in [CV](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @user227710: Yes, I'm hitting walls every way I turn. Thanks for the guidance. I'm going to take your advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is tobit-2 model and hence you assume you observe faminc only for those who have lfp=1.  So lfp is always 1 for the observed outcomes.  Hence it is not be identified (separately from constant).

There is a new version of sampleSelection coming that does this (currently under r-forge in branches/treatReg).  Hope to get it out in a couple of weeks.